# On iOS, how do I explicitly download a photo or video that's in iCloud while using iCloud Photo Library?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I'm an iCloud Photo Library user.  How can I specifically ensure that a specific video/photo is downloaded locally on my iOS device?

Basically I'm looking for the equivalent of a "Download" button available on a photo or video so that it will be available locally on the iPhone.

Basically, there are some apps that don't really handle deal with iCloud based media well, so I want to ensure that the media is available locally so I can accomplish my task in the 3rd party app (Magisto).

Answer (score 1):

If your device is **not** set to Optimize Storage, it will not remove a download, meaning you can then go open the photo in Photos and it will be there permanently.

Additionally, if it's a short time frame this will work even with Optimize Storage.

Comment: I have Optimize Storage turned on. I can't turn it off because I have more than will fit on my device

Comment: Right, so if you need a photo to be downloaded, the only way you can currently do this is to open the photo and go to the app immediately after. I do not know when it will delete, but it's not immediately.

Answer (score 0):

have you filed a case with our support team yet?

please ping me at gil at magisto dot com, I'll see if I can get someone to help you.

Gil